# Plot-Error with multidimensional "X" and "y" that have only one dimension

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I want to build a model that can predict how many bike will be rented. Therefore i am using the DecisionTreeRegressor but i have a problem. I can not plot this because "ValueError: x and y must be the same size". If i compare X and y with len(), i get the same length. The problem is that my X got 10 columns and y only 1 column. Thats why i get this error.
I want to get the following picture with my plot:

[image: Picture i want to get with the code below]

Any ideas how i can correct this?

```
X = df_day.drop(["date", "total_rides"], axis = 1)
y = df_day["total_rides"]
#X has something like 10 columns and y has only 1 column

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 43, test_size = 0.25)

dtc = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth = None)
dtc.fit(X_train, y_train)
#dtc.score(X_test, y_test)

#Prediction
y_pred2 = dtc.predict(X_test)
plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If x has 10 columns how can you plot it against y in 2d plot? what you want to achieve from plotting this data?

Comment: I still have problems to understand what exactly is your problem. Can you amend example data that illustrate what you got and what you want? (maybe not 10 days, but 3 days, not 24 hours, but 4 hours for simplicity's sake)

Answer (score 0):

Like your error says, you can only plot arrays that have the same size (i.e. one x-column and one y-column or ten x-columns and ten y-columns, all with the same number of rows). To plot them all together, you should repeat the y values for each column. Naively:

```
for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    plt.scatter(X[:,i], y)
    plt.plot(X_test[:,i], y_pred2)

plt.show()
```

Note that these columns are likely all on different scales and this plot will probably be quite meaningless. But the code should show you want you wanted to see.

Comment: Hey and thank you for your answer! I did it wrong. I want to plot y (total_bikes = count of bikes that were soled) over the time, so x["date"]. But i get the following error now "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'". Maybe you could help me ?

Comment: I can't help without seeing the code. Can you please show what the line is that you're trying to run?

Comment: Below you can see the code of my model:
    X = df_day.drop(["total_rides"], axis = 1)
    y = df_day["total_rides"]
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 43, test_size = 0.25)
    dtc = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth = None)
    dtc.fit(X_train, y_train)

Comment: Now i want to build a diagram that shows me the true count of rented bikes over the time (X_test, y_test) and the predicted curve (X_test, y_predicted). 
Below you can see my code to get two curves with following error - "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'"            
    y_predicted = dtc.predict(X_test)
    plt.plot(X_test["date"], y)
    plt.plot(X_test["date"], y_pred2)
    plt.show()
How can i display my curves?
What do you think about my machine learning model? Should i choose another one?

Comment: Seems like your `X["date"]` column is a `Timestamp` type which is not supported by `matplotlib`. Try this: `plt.plot(X_test["date"].dt.to_pydatetime(), y); plt.plot(X_test["date"].dt.to_pydatetime(), y_pred2); plt.show()`.

Though you probably shouldn't be including the raw date in your training data, this might be giving you trouble as well.